# With regex, how can I individually capture a variable number of words?

Tags: python, regex

I have a random number of things in a string I want to capture.

For example, given "The basket contains apples, grapes, bread, squash",

I want a list made up of `["apples", "grapes", "bread", "squash"]`.

I do not know how many unique items will be in the basket. There may be 10 or 0 things.

The matching pattern `contains ((?:(\w+),? ?)*)` doesn't work.

The outer parenthesis matches `apples, grapes, bread, squash` and the inner parenthesis only matches `squash`!

Comment: That makes sense `squash` is last capture, in quantified expressions, groups are overwritten each quantified pass. How do you plan to overcome that?

Comment: The easiest way is to take the matched contents of group 1 and to split on the delimiter in another operation. The harder way is to use exotic `\G` anchor frought with complexity.

Comment: My problem was that python has multiple regex methods. I was only using re.search() instead of re.findall(). I'm familliar with Perl where most of the results are determined by the pattern instead of what function you call

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
(\w+(?=,|$))(?!.*contains)
```

[Regex live here.](https://regex101.com/r/jB1xL7/2)

Comment: No dice. There is my line for line output in python:


>>> line = "The basket contains apples, grapes, bread, squash"
>>> match = re.search("(\w+(?=,|$))(?!.*contains)", line)
>>> match.groups()
('apples',)

Comment: This pattern works with re.findal(). I was using re.search(). Thank you